# Netbeans / Java / Delete Files on Mac

Tags: java, macos, delete-file

I have a problem with my Java program. I want to delete a file on my hdd; I use a MacBook.
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    File actualFile = new File("/Users/luffy/test.xml");
    actualFile.delete();
}
```

`chmod` is set! Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file is not in use by another program.

Make sure that you have closed all streams accessing this file.

Comment: On a mac/UNIX the file used by another program won't cause any problem. Same thing for the streams.